Use JPQL or SQL to SELECT items _not_ in the database from a supplied set in the query parameters
I have an interesting problem, I need to figure out which files I have not processed.
I have an object called ReturnFile(return_files) that stores the ones I've processed. I'd like to issue a query that has a parameter Set<String> called availableFiles, and have it return just the strings from my supplied Set that are not in the database.
@Entity
ReturnFile {
  @Column
  private String fileName;
}

So given the database had the following inside the return_files table: file1, file2, file3, and the sftp has file2, file4, I'd want to supply the files on the sftp as a parameter and get back an answer of file4.
I'm struggling to figure out how to do this even with plain JDBC parameters. As much as I would love a JPQL solution, an SQL solution would be great to. Thank you for any help!

I think of these ways: (1) There should be database-specific ways involving the manipulation of SQL arrays. What is your DB? (2) If the size of the availableFiles and the size of the table are relatively small you can invert the question to the DB, i.e. select the set of files that exist from the DB (SELECT fileName FROM ReturnFile WHERE fileName IN (...availableFiles...)) and do the set difference in Java. Is this the case? I think both solutions would be affected by the size of the return_files table and if you can limit the searched rows.

We also thought about doing the difference in Java. At small levels of n, this wouldn't be an issue, but as we scale into hundreds of thousands of files, it would be.

It turns out this is a really hard problem to solve in SQL: "Dear Database, tell me everything in this list I'm supplying to you that is not present in this table".
This is the query we came up with. If you have a better solution, please post it as an answer!
Note the parameter ? is a list of filenames encoded as a JSON array. Those have been escaped to avoid JSON injection attacks.
SELECT
    available_files.file_name
FROM
    JSON_TABLE(
        ?,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            file_name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
        )
    ) AS available_files
LEFT JOIN return_files rf ON available_files.file_name = rf.original_file_name
WHERE
    rf.original_file_name IS NULL;

